# FullCalendar add resources default event values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

The below example is working good. I want to add the default values for resources follow like sample image(0,1) I attached. I searched many ans but it will not help me to achieve the result.

[image: Sample Image]
I have tried the below format code.

```
{"resourceId":"h","title":"event 4","start":"0","end":"0"}],
{"resourceId":"i","title":"event 5","start":"1","end":"1"}]
```

Comment for further information. Thanks!!

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'resourceTimeline' ],
    header: {
      left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
 editable: true,
    resources: [{"id":"a","title":"Auditorium A"},{"id":"b","title":"Auditorium B"},
 {"id":"c","title":"Auditorium C"},
 {"id":"d","title":"Auditorium D","children":[{"id":"d1","title":"Room D1"},
 {"id":"d2","title":"Room D2"}]},
 {"id":"e","title":"Auditorium E"},
 {"id":"f","title":"Auditorium F"},
 {"id":"g","title":"Auditorium G"},
 {"id":"h","title":"Auditorium H"},
 {"id":"i","title":"Auditorium I"}],
 events: [{"resourceId":"d","title":"event 1","start":"2019-08-04","end":"2019-08-06"},
 {"resourceId":"c","title":"event 3","start":"2019-08-05T12:00:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-06T06:00:00+00:00"},
 {"resourceId":"f","title":"event 4","start":"2019-08-05T07:30:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-05T09:30:00+00:00"},
 {"resourceId":"b","title":"event 5","start":"2019-08-05T10:00:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-05T15:00:00+00:00"},
 {"resourceId":"e","title":"event 2","start":"2019-08-05T09:00:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-05T14:00:00+00:00"}]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/interaction/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-common/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Is that a premium only feature?

Comment: @10101010 I am not sure about that.

Comment: Also the image you posted is that your design or did you see it somewhere?

Comment: `"start":"0","end":"0"` doesn't make sense. They have to be dates.

Comment: @10101010 The image I designed myself. I just tried the `start:0`.

Comment: I think you should try creating events for individual timings and style the events the way you want it.

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197478/discussion-between-10101010-and-saravana).

Comment: You can't just put those 1s and 0s directly into the timeslots like that. (If you look at the rendered HTML of the calendar using your browser's inspector, you'll see that in fact there is no single HTML element representing a cell on the calendar - instead it is constructed of different tables layered on top of each other, so you will be unable to position your data correctly).

Comment: Instead I suggest you simply add this information as extra event objects in your `events` property. e.g. `{"resourceId":"h","title":"0","start":""2019-08-05T06:00:00+00:00","end":""2019-08-05T07:00:00+00:00", "backgroundColor": "green"}]` for the first `0` in resource H. (I gave it a different background colour just to make it seem different from the regular events.) You could even separate this data into a different event source, for neatness. Either that, or consider a different way of communicating this information to your user - I'm not sure what these numbers actually represent?